# How to convert from array to matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I would like to seek a help to convert from a list into the matrix. I have a list of array like this:

```
output [[[ 0.]
         [ 0.]
         [ 0.]
         [ 1.]]

         [[ 0.]
          [ 0.]
          [ 1.]
          [ 0.]]

         [[ 0.]
          [ 0.]
          [ 1.]
          [ 0.]]]
```

And I need to convert it in the matrix:

```
X [matrix([[0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [1]]), matrix([[0],
    [0],
    [1],
    [0]]), matrix([[0],
    [0],
    [1],
    [0]])
```

Hopefully, somebody may help me. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `array(x)`?

Comment: I mean the output need to be converted into the matrix form.
`X [matrix([[0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [1]]), matrix([[0],
    [0],
    [1],
    [0]]), matrix([[0],
    [0],
    [1],
    [0]])`

Comment: This is quite straight forward: Given, `list = [[[ 0.], [ 0.], [ 0.], [ 1.]], [[ 0.], [ 0.], [ 1.],  [ 0.]],  [[ 0.], [ 0.], [ 1.], [ 0.]]]` required output: `list_of_mat = [np.matrix(i) for i in list]`

Comment: Thank you so much @Mankind_008. 
That is the good answer.